# Strip blanks at the beginning & trailing blanks in AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I am asking for your assistance to strip blanks/spaces before & at the end each field. ie Remove the trailing space from the $1, the same apply to the beginning & trailing spaces in $2, and the leading spaces from $3 using AWK on AIX 7.2 platform. Below is some data in the file Employee.txt

```
001 |  George John Aden Brown   | gbrown
002 |   Barry Street White      | bwhite
003 |    Kelly Jones            | kjones
004 |   Jolene Davidson Smith   | jsmith
```

My objective is to achieve the following set of data (without the leading/trailing spaces)

```
001|George John Aden Brown|gbrown
002|Barry Street White|bwhite
003|Kelly Jones|kjones
004|Jolene Davidson Smith|jsmith
```

I have tried the following without satisfaction.

```
awk -F"|" '{ print $1 "|" gsub(" ", "", $2) "|" $3 }' Employee.txt
awk -F"|" '{ print $1 "|" gsub(/[ \t]/,"",$2) "|" $3 }'  Employee.txt
awk -F"|" '{ print $1 "|" gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", $2) "|" $3 }' Employee.txt

001 |8| gbrown
002 |11| bwhite
003 |17| kjones
004 |8| jsmith
```

Comment: Try this: sed 's/ *| */|/g; s/^ *//; s/ *$//

Comment: Regarding `Remove the trailing space from the $1, the same apply to the beginning & trailing spaces in $2, and the leading spaces from $3` - so, since you specifically excluded them, you don't want leading spaces at the start of the line or trailing spaces at the end of it removed, right?

Comment: I am pleased to find out how useful sed 's/ *| */|/g; s/^ *//; s/ *$//' which stripped out all blank spaces before & trailing from 3 (all) columns. Thank you very much 
Zsigmond Lőrinczy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually - and a LOT:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"                 # set both separators to pipe
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)         # loop all fields
        gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$i)  # strip leading and trailing space
}1' file                       # output
```

Output:

```
001|George John Aden Brown|gbrown
002|Barry Street White|bwhite
003|Kelly Jones|kjones
004|Jolene Davidson Smith|jsmith
```

If you got other junk there, feel free to tune the regex:

```
gsub(/^"?[ \t]*(N\/A)?|[ \t]*"?$/),"",$i)  # etc
```

Comment: The initial suggestion has worked perfectly. However, I am more interested in getting $2 content but awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$2) }1' Employee.txt without the for loop also include $1 & $3 which I don't want. How to get the value of $2 only? Thanks again.

Comment: In that case you need to lose the outputting with just `1` that outputs the whole record and use `print $2`, ie. `'BEGIN{FS="|"}{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$2);print $2}'`

Comment: ... or `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|”}{$2=gsub(/ /,"",$2)}1'` for your last expected output. You really should make up your mind, man.

Comment: Thank you James. 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$2);print $2}' worked like a charm.

Comment: Could you please explain what the regular expression /^ +| +$/ mean? Thanks a lot

Comment: `/^ +` = all the leading space `|` or `+$/` all the trailing space. Basically replaces all leading or trailing space with `""` nothing.

Comment: Is the | used in the gsub() regular expression as a field delimiter. ie strip all spaces from the pipe (separates $1 & $2) up to the first alphanumeric character (left) and apply the same action to any spaces between the last character to the pipe (right) that separates $2 & $3? Thanks again

Comment: In regex `|` means OR. "Trim space from the beginning OR the end of the field" - or both (if there was AND operator in regex that would require trimming from the beginning AND the end and would fail if there was space to trim only in the beginning or the end).

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as `[[:space:]]+\\|[[:space:]]+`(spaces followed by pipe followed by spaces) for all the lines of Input_file then setting `OFS` as `|` for all the lines. In main program then resetting `$1` to itself to actually apply new value of `OFS` to whole line, once its done, simple printing that line by mentioning `1`.

```
awk -v FS='[[:space:]]+\\|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: This has stripped out all the space in $1, $2 but left the trailing spaces of $3. How to fix this up? Also, how to use the same command to get the content of $2 only? Thanks again

Comment: @GeorgeJackson, sure to remove initial and trailing spaces try `awk -v FS='[[:space:]]+\\|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1;gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$,/,"")} 1' Input_file` once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @GeorgeJackson, Above command had been tested with starting and trailing spaces also and it worked fine for me, please do check once and revert in case any queries.

Comment: FS='[[:space:]]+\\|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1;gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$,/,"")} 1' Employee.txt got the same outcome as your initial suggestion. ie there are remaining trailing spaces in $3. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

You've got good awk answers. However if you want to consider `sed` this is pretty simple with:

```sh
sed -E 's/ *(\|) *|^ +| +$/\1/g' file

001|George John Aden Brown|gbrown
002|Barry Street White|bwhite
003|Kelly Jones|kjones
004|Jolene Davidson Smith|jsmith
```

Or else with `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk '{print gensub(/ *(\|) *|^ +| +$/, "\\1", "g")}' file
```

PS: This `sed` command requires `GNU` or `BSD` versions.

Comment: Thanks anubhava but I am looking for an AWK solution to be able to pick & choose & manipulate multiple columns of data.

Comment: Got the following syntax error in AIX 7.2. I try to replace -E with multiple -e switches without success though. Thanks
bash-4.3$ sed -E 's/ *(\|) *|^ +| +$/\1/g' Employee.txt
sed: Not a recognized flag: E
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
bash-4.3$ sed -e 's/ *(\|)/g' -e 's/ *|^/g' -e 's/ +| +$/\1/g' Employee.txt
sed: 0602-404 Function s/ *(\|)/g cannot be parsed.

Comment: Try this on AIX sed: `sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; s/ *\| */|/g' file`

Comment: sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; s/ *\| */|/g' did stripped all the blanks (before & after) for all 3 columns. Let me try explain my understanding of these regular expressions: s/^ *//; (strip all blanks on $1 from the beginning of the line & replace them with nothing). s/ *$//; (search for starting space(s) in $2 & replace them with nothing). s/ *\| */|/g (not sure what this do?). Also not sure if each search are applied to each field. ie the left for $1, middle for $2 and right for $3, or all 3 regular expressions are applied for each field ($1,$2,$3)? Thanks again.

Comment: `sed` command is applied to full line but due to anchors in regex `s/^ *//;` is applied to first field and `s/ *$//;` is applied to last field only. `s/ *\| */|/g` is applied to any middle field by stripping spaces around delimiter `|` .

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said in your question, you don't want leading or trailing spaces on the lines removed then using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/ *| */|/g' file
001|George John Aden Brown|gbrown
002|Barry Street White|bwhite
003|Kelly Jones|kjones
004|Jolene Davidson Smith|jsmith
```

otherwise if you actually did want the leading/trailing blanks removed too then with GNU or BSD sed for `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^| *)\|( *|$)/|/g' file
001|George John Aden Brown|gbrown
002|Barry Street White|bwhite
003|Kelly Jones|kjones
004|Jolene Davidson Smith|jsmith
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, but I am looking for an AWK solution to be able to pick & choose & manipulate multiple columns of data.

Answer (score 0):

Also with `awk`

```
awk '{$2=$2;gsub(/ \| /,"|")} 1' file
001|George John Aden Brown|gbrown
002|Barry Street White|bwhite
003|Kelly Jones|kjones
004|Jolene Davidson Smith|jsmith
```

- `The stripping of leading and trailing whitespace also comes into play whenever $0 is recomputed.` (see: http://gnu.ist.utl.pt/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html )
- `$2=$2` The assignment of `$2` to `$2` rebuilds `$0`. Now we have a new `$0` without leading and trailing whitespace.
- And we apply to `$0` the `gsub()` function: regexp `/ \| /` for space followed by `|` character followed by space. This is substituted by `|` character.

Comment: That would change any white space (e.g. tab or 2 blanks) between words within a field to single blank chars.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. awk '{$2=$2;gsub(/ \| /,"|")} 1' stripped out blanks for all 3 columns. How about just getting the content of $2? Could you please explain what the command means? Many thanks.

Comment: @George, If we do $2=$2 (or any other assignment to a field) `awk` rebuilds $0. You have an explanation with its example in the url of the manual: http://gnu.ist.utl.pt/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html

Comment: `How about just getting the content of $2?`  It is explained in the @JamesBrown's comments.